# Pandas drop list of booleans, what does it do?

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please explain me what does this do?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4),
                      columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

>>> df.drop([True, True])
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   2   3
2   8   9   10  11

>>> df.drop([True, True, True, True, True, True])
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   2   3
2   8   9   10  11
```

Thank you

Comment: pandas treat boolean True as 1 ,  so in both cases index 1 is dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pd.DataFrame.drop` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) helps here:

```
DataFrame.drop(labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None,  
               level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')
```

- `axis=0` default means `drop` is applied to rows by default.
- `labels` means index for `axis=0` or columns for `axis=1`.

Since `bool` is a subclass of `int`, `True` is treated in old versions of `pandas` as 1 and `False` as 0. `df.drop` is not designed for use with Boolean arrays. For Boolean indexing using `df.loc`.

To drop rows by index position, you can supply a list to `df.index`:

```
df.drop(df.index[[1,3]])
```